# Node.js Module.exports strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cluster-computing

I'm working on a express app and came over a strange behaviour regarding `module.exports`.

**server.js**

```
var server = cluster(app).use(cluster.debug()).listen(3000);
module.exports.cluster = server;
```

**index.js**

```
// Works
var server = require('./server');
console.log(server.cluster); // = Cluster object

# Doesn't work:
var server = require('./server').cluster;
console.log(server); // = undefiend
```

In my opinion both solutions *should* work as they do when working with mongoose or so. This only occurs when exporting learnboost's `cluster`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's likely that you have a cyclic dependency in your modules, so the exported object isn't actually ready at it's first point of call.

Comment: so the second one will never work, except the exported value is ready like strings and stuff?

Comment: It depends, I would need to see all of the `require()` calls in both files to confirm what is possible; looks like you've only shared part.

Comment: Yepp, that was just a part. Complete code:

**server.js**: http://pastie.org/2750393
**index.js**: http://pastie.org/2750387

Comment: Doesn't look problematic, unless `app` requires things that you haven't posted.

Comment: Nope, `app` is just a express server. When putting the two mentioned lines into the `exports` part of **index.js**, `require('../server').cluster` works... Maybe some kind of scope issue?